# SwiftUI with associated ViewModel Type can't be initialised from its hosting ViewController with Swift 5.7

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, swift5.7

I am defining a SwiftUI view with an associated ViewModel protocol type. However, I getting this error while building `Type 'any MyViewModelType' cannot conform to 'MyViewModelType'`.

Here's my full code.

```
protocol MyViewModelType: ObservableObject {
    var loadData: CGFloat { get }
}


struct MyView<ViewModel>: View where ViewModel: MyViewModelType {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: any MyViewModelType) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel as! ViewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
    }
}

class SubscriptionViewV2Controller: UIHostingController<MyView<MyViewModelType>> {
    init(viewModel: any MyViewModelType) {
        super.init(rootView: MyView(viewModel: viewModel))
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }

    @MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Additionally, I dont know why Xcode would throw error here

```
init(viewModel: any MyViewModelType) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel as! ViewModel
}
```

Because of that error, I need to force cast `viewModel` assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI generics need one concrete Type to work with. This could be any `MyViewModelType`. But you have to specify that it will be only one specific. `any` is the exact opposite.

```
protocol MyViewModelType: ObservableObject {
    var loadData: CGFloat { get }
}

struct MyView<T>: View where T: MyViewModelType {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: T

    init(viewModel: T) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi")
    }
}

class SubscriptionViewV2Controller<T>: UIHostingController<MyView<T>> where T: MyViewModelType {
    init(viewModel: T) {
        super.init(rootView: MyView(viewModel: viewModel))
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }

    @MainActor @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[This](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110353/) could shed some light on it.

Also [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110352/).